# How to add @parameter annotation for TestNG in Eclipse

Tags: selenium, testng

I'm trying to do parameterization for TestNG in Eclipse but the annotation `@parameter` is not being shown.
How to add `@parameter` annotation for TestNG in eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to add TestNG parameters annotations to pass parameters to your test method?
TestNG uses `@Parameter` annotation for this purpose. Try with capitalized letters.

```
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
@Parameters
public class helloWorldTest {
    @Parameters(value="blah")
    public void testHelloWord() {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you pass parameters from your testng.xml file into your tests using TestNG.  There are 2 ways you can do it:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.ITestContext;

public class helloWorldTest {

    @Parameters(value="blah")
    @Test       
    public void testDirectParameters() {
        System.out.println(blah);
    }

    @Test       
    public void testIndirectParameters(ITestContext context) {
        String blahString = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("blah");
        System.out.println(blahString);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

including above make sure that you have included testng jar in your project.
If you have maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```